# implement custom partitioning with windowAll()

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to implement custom partitioning with windowing in apache flink. Currently I have the following:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> split = operatorAggregateStream
                .partitionCustom(new RoundRobin(), value->value.f0 )
                .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                .process(new MaxPartialWindowProcessFunction());
```

The issue is that I need windowing but using `windowAll` overrides my partitioning and creates a different partitioning.

my new solution is to forcefully implement myself the windowing but I feel that this is overkill. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The [windowAll](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#windowAll-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.WindowAssigner-) operation forces a parallelism of 1 (all records have to be sent to the same sub-task), since it operators on a non-keyed stream. This is why the partitioning you did previously isn't useful, as Flink will insert a rebalance that forces the stream parallelism to be 1.

You said "I need windowing", which means you need a keyed stream. You can do operations on partitioned records without windowing, but you won't be able to use timers to trigger window evaluations, as that requires a keyed stream.

Comment: Hi :) the goal is to have windowing but distributed along the different subtasks to then be flushed at the same time for all subtasks. If i take your answer that you made in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181835/implementation-of-roundrobin-partitioning-in-apache-flink/78188491#78188491 it seems that my hopes of a "distributed" windowing does not exist in flink and thus I would have to create this myself.